# regex matching when not trailing slash

Tags: regex, slash, trailing

How would a regex look like when i have the input

```
foo.bar/level/1A
foo.bar/level/1A/test
foo.bar/level/1B
foo.bar/level/1A/blabl/sdffs
foo.bar/test
```

As a result I only want the urls where the root items in the level folder so

```
foo.bar/level/1A
```

and

```
foo.bar/level/1B
```

So anything in the level folder that is nog followed by a slash basicly
What is the best regex way to extract these ?

Thx (I realy need to find a good regex training cause I always bump into this stuff when there is look ahead / back and stuff involved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[^\/]*\/level\/[^\/]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iqnsjV/1